# Airplay Install Error cannot create /usr/local/man/man1

Tags: raspbian, perl, amazon

I was following this tutorial to clone Alexa. At the bottom, I was installing AirPlay with [this](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-build-your-own-amazon-echo-with-a-raspberry-pi-1787726931) command:

```
sudo ./Build install
```

I got this error:

```
Building Net-SDP
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/man/man1'
mkdir /usr/local/man: File exists at /usr/share/perl/5.20/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 476.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at /usr/share/perl5/Module/Build/Base.pm line 3560.
```

I used the file manager to go to usr/local and found that `man` has a red triangular symbol, which says symbolic link. This might be related to the error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you asked the person who created the tutorial?  They will be in the  best position to advise.

Comment: I looked online and makezine has the exact same tutorial for installing AirPlay, as do many other articles. This installation that I used is unrelated to Amazon Echo. @joan